# Rotating labels with PieDonut in R 4.2.1

Tags: r, label, pie-chart

I'm making a PieDonut chart with R 4.2.1 and the donut labels are all clustered together, changing font size doesn't help. Is there a way to offset the labels a certain distance from the donut? Or rotate them?

Here's my current code:

```
PieDonut(data, aes(Category, Detail, count=Amount), title = "June", 
        showRatioDonut = FALSE, showRatioPie = FALSE, pieLabelSize = 3,
        labelposition = 10, labelpositionThreshold = 1, use.label = TRUE,
        donutLabelSize = 3, showRatioThreshold = FALSE)
```

Edited to add data:

```
structure(list(Detail = c("Payroll", "Lab services", "Distribution", 
"Office supplies", "Tech supplies", "Dental supplies", "Loan", 
"Rent", "Taxes", "Processing fees", "Misc", "One time", "Unknown", 
"CDA Dues", "Housekeeping", "CME", "Accounting services", "Utilities", 
"Gas", "Car", "Life insurance", "Insurance", "Lunch"), Category = c("Payroll", 
"Lab", "Distribution", "Supplies", "Supplies", "Supplies", "Loan", 
"Rent", "Taxes", "Misc", "Misc", "Misc", "Misc", "Services", 
"Services", "Services", "Services", "Services", "Car", "Car", 
"Insurance", "Insurance", "Lunch"), Amount = c(55879.8, 18000, 
15000, 1527.7, 3269.96, 8005.54, 9106.06, 6509, 5468, 15, 180.23, 
529.06, 2629.6, 167.92, 250, 448, 550, 590.1, 269.47, 406.99, 
101.47, 719.34, 110.33)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

Comment: I would suggest creating an issue for this on GitHub. It seems not possible at the moment.